# Gson for Maven - Failed to determine Java version for profile

Tags: java, maven, gson

I am trying to use NetBeans to install Gson as a Maven dependency. Here is my pom entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I used 'Manually Install Artifact' to install Gson via jar file locally.

However, when I clicked 'View Artifact Details', I encounter the following error:

> Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>
> [ERROR] Failed to determine Java version for profile
>   doclint-java8-disable @ com.google.code.gson:gson-parent:2.6.2,
>   C:\Users\muhammadims.2013.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson-parent\2.6.2\gson-parent-2.6.2.pom,
>   line 108, column 14  for project.

Would this be an issue when running the project? Please help resolve. Thanks

Comment: I think you can safely ignore that. The dependency info is correct, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just wanna include gson jar into project as per pom entry. Here you can just right click project -> Run As -> Maven clean. This will download gson artifact into your project(see screen shot below)

[image]